# Difference between ST_Simplify function in PostGIS 3.0.0 and PostGIS 2.5.3

Tags: postgis, postgresql, algorithm, analysis

Faced such a problem (or maybe it's a bug).
I get different results when using the ST_Simplify function in PostGIS 3.0.0 and PostGIS 2.5.3.

There are source data that are simplified by using a query:

```
SELECT ST_Simplify(geometry, 20) FROM source_table
```

For verification, I created two databases on different OS. PostgreSQL11-PostGIS-3 and PostgreSQL11-PostgiGIS-2.5 with the same data mapping and SRID.

Result:

Postgis 2.5.3
[image]
[image]

Postgis 3.0.0[image]

PostGIS 3 lost a lot of small hole geometries, although the source data and the request are the same. Why is this happening and how to fix it in PostGIS-3?

**Update**

Yes, SRID 3857 in both cases.

I try `ST_Simplify(geometry, 20, false)` and `ST_Simplify(geometry, 20, true)` in Postgis 3 it did not help.

Postgis_full_version();
POSTGIS="3.0.0 r17983" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="110" GEOS="3.7.2-CAPI-1.11.2 b55d2125" PROJ="Rel. 5.2.0, September 15th, 2018" LIBXML="2.9.4" LIBJSON="0.13.1" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.1" WAGYU="0.4.3 (Internal)"

Comment: As per documentation, there is no change in ST_Siplify function between 2.5 and 3.0. Maybe a bug? Maybe try to call this function with preserveCollapsed parameter set to true. Or did you try ST_SimlifyVW? By my experiences, it produces better results...

Comment: There are some changes in handling the 3rd parameter (https://github.com/postgis/postgis/commit/9faea6ee94f585b15f03666cfb66275184505f2f#diff-90b256cf1e5d8b30dae5ba77560be108). Should be set to false by default for 2.5 as well as for 3.0, but I'm not a C expert. Definitely a thing to try...

Comment: It would be much easier to test if you could provide some test data. Are you sure about having data in same SRID in both databases?

Comment: do you get the same results for different runs on both versions?

Comment: @user30184 yes same SRID  in both databases

Comment: @ThingumaBob the results are different. Although the data and request are the same

Comment: @DavidP I try ST_Simplify(geometry, 20, false) and ST_Simplify(geometry, 20, true) in Postgis 3 it did not help.

Comment: @user30184 Test data: https://osmdata.openstreetmap.de/download/water-polygons-split-4326.zip

Comment: Actually this should create fine debug info. Edit to suit with your data, run in both databases and attach the outputs into your question `select ST_AsEWKT("GEOMETRY") as original, ST_AsEWKT(ST_Simplify("GEOMETRY",0.1)) as simplified
from my_table limit 1;`

Comment: @user30184 
Where can I send it?

Comment: If it is too large to fit as a text into the question area put it into any file share service you like, for example send.firefox.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Bug #4568: Oversimplification of polygon inner rings in ST_Simplify](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/4568) was fixed in PostGIS 3.0.1.